# how to implement a counter to dynamically create a tic tac toe board

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am creating a tic tac toe board where users can input their rows and columns. It works for a standard 3x3 but I want to make it so it can go to 99x99 if I wanted to. It works for that but the problem is the columns keep increasing by 1 for each row you add. For example, to make a 6x6, you need to input 9 columns instead of 6. I was wondering what should be added to make it so it can do automatically instead of the user having to hard input.

code is here:

```
class toe:
   marker = '|'
   def __init__(self, row, col):
       self.row = row
       self.col = col

   def create_board(self):
       d = self.col + 2
       final = []
       board = ['-' * d for i in range(self.row)]
       print(board)
       for i in board:
           for j in enumerate(i):
               excel = list(j)
               if excel[0] % 2 != 0:
                   excel[1] = self.marker
           final.append(excel[1])
       arr2 = [final[l:l+d] for l in range(0, len(final), d)] 
       for m in arr2:
           print(''.join(m))

def main():
   print('to make a correct board after a 3x3, add 1 to the columns. Ex: 4x4 is 4 rows and 5   columns')
   print('Ex: 5x5 is 5 rows and 7 columns. 6x6 is 6 rows 9 columns')
   row = int(input('number of rows: '))
   col = int(input('number of columns: '))
   create = toe(row, col)
   create.create_board()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just by the way here, but winning even a standard 3x3 board requires one of the players to make obvious errors - going larger makes it even more difficult to get a win before being blocked. There are variants with larger boards, but they all seem to have more complex rules.

Comment: Could you explain more ? >Code does not seem to work. As is it not very clear. Add "main()", and maybee just do create = toe(row, col+1), as a dirty and quick idea to fix it.

Comment: yeah i dont really stackoverflow that much and i was trying to add the main part but it kept not being adding to the code snippet. let me try again

Comment: "It works for a standard 3x3"? On my machine, the output is quite weird, far from Tic Tac Toe.

Comment: yes on my machine, the output on the terminal shows a 3x3 when you input 3 for rows and 3 for columns.

Comment: just to clarify in the future, I have completely changed how the code looks since this post and I have everything working except having the board have the right dimensions in the code and the user having to do it manually for anything bigger than a 3x3